# auto login to website when redirected from intuit

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am failing this part of the certification:

```
If signed out of App, but signed into the App Center, the App should launch when launching from the App Center without asking for credentials
```

I am basing my application on intuits "HelloIntuitAnywhere" c# demo which uses DotNetOpenAuth.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region OpenId

        // Hide Connect to Quickbooks widget and show Sign in widget
        IntuitInfo.Visible = false;
        IntuitSignin.Visible = true;
        // If Session has keys
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Count > 0)
        {
            // If there is a key OpenIdResponse
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["OpenIdResponse"] != null)
            {
                // Show the Sign in widget and disable the Connect to Quickbooks widget
                IntuitSignin.Visible = false;
                IntuitInfo.Visible = true;
            }

            // Sow information of the user if the keys are in the session
            if (Session["FriendlyIdentifier"] != null)
            {
                friendlyIdentifier.Text = Session["friendlyIdentifier"].ToString();
            }
            if (Session["FriendlyName"] != null)
            {
                friendlyName.Text = Session["FriendlyName"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                friendlyName.Text = "User Didnt Login Via OpenID, look them up in your system";
            }

            if (Session["FriendlyEmail"] != null)
            {
                friendlyEmail.Text = Session["FriendlyEmail"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                friendlyEmail.Text = "User Didnt Login Via OpenID, look them up in your system";
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region oAuth

        // If session has accesstoken and InvalidAccessToken is null
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["accessToken"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["InvalidAccessToken"] == null)
        {
            // Show oAuthinfo(contains Get Customers Quickbooks List) and disable Connect to quickbooks widget
            oAuthinfo.Visible = true;
            connectToIntuitDiv.Visible = false;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

How do I identify that the user is already signed in to the App Center and by-pass my login screen/section?

I have this piece of code (from OpenIdHandler.aspx.cs) that works EXCEPT I want to to not redirect to the intuit login page when the user is not logged in. I want to display the login button.

```
    public partial class OpenIdHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Action Results for Index, uses DotNetOpenAuth for creating OpenId Request with Intuit
    /// and handling response recieved. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event Args.</param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //OpenId Relying Party
        OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

        var openIdIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["openid_identifier"];
        var response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (response == null)
        {
            // Stage 2: user submitting Identifier
            Identifier id;
            if (Identifier.TryParse(openIdIdentifier, out id))
            {
                try
                {
                    IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(openIdIdentifier);
                    FetchRequest fetch = new FetchRequest();
                    fetch.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email));
                    fetch.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName));
                    request.AddExtension(fetch);
                    request.RedirectToProvider();
                }
                catch (ProtocolException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/OpenIdHandler.aspx");
            }

            // Stage 3: OpenID Provider sending assertion response
            Session["FriendlyIdentifier"] = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;
            FetchResponse fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
            if (fetch != null)
            {
                Session["OpenIdResponse"] = "True";
                Session["FriendlyEmail"] = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
                Session["FriendlyName"] = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);
            }

            //Check if user disconnected from the App Center
            if (Request.QueryString["disconnect"] != null && Request.QueryString["disconnect"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == "true")
            {
                Session["Flag"] = true;
                Response.Redirect("CleanupOnDisconnect.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the user is redirected to your application from the App Center, use OpenID to fetch the user's email address and sign them into your app.  Since the user has already authorized the connection, you will also be able to fetch the realmId.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0011_from_the_intuit_app_center/implement_openid_in_your_app

Comment: When the user clicks on the application in "My Apps" what URL is it going to use? I have "App URL" and "OpenID URL" both pointing to to https://mywebsite.com/OpenIdHandler.aspx but apparently it is pointing https://mywebsite.com or https://mywebsite.com/Login.aspx. I have recently changed it to https://mywebsite.com/OpenIdHandler.aspx. Does it take a while to trickle down?

Comment: It will call the App URL. The OpenID URL is called when a user subscribes through the App Center. It should not take any time to update once you save your app settings.

Answer (score 1):

My fix is two fold:

1. In the Intuit application manager I set the App URL: mywebsite.com/OpenIdHandler.aspx
2. I was basing my application on the intuit demo... In Global.asax.cs I removed the redirect which was causing all my problems since no matter what I would be redirected to default.aspx (which in turn redirects me to login).

   ```
   void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Code that runs when a new session is started
       //Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); //<-----
   }
   ```

Thanks.